# how to use oracle sqlldr to load excel csv file without comma at end

Tags: oracle, csv, sql-loader

I have csv file as:
1,2,3
control file: fields terminated by ','
however, when I load the data, I got ORA-01722 invalid number.
if I add , at the end of the file like 1,2,3, then all three columns will be loaded, is there any option to load all three columns without ending comma?

Comment: I wonder if you have some non-printing character at the end of some or all records.  Generally, there's no need to have the trailing comma for sqlldr to work.

Comment: Here's a working example, which might help as a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53317198/read-data-from-csv-fileseperated-by-comma-data-using-sql-loader-when-there

Comment: It could be a carriage return, if the file was created in WIndows and loaded in Unix/Linux. [This is very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36409049/266304); there the extra character made the value too big, but with a number column it would cause this error.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the help. I did save in windows and loaded into Unix. I checked my file, it has control M, carriage return, once I deleted \r, I was able to load successfully. Thank you all.

Comment: @xiaoyunwu - glad you solved your poblem. Why not turn your comment into a proper answer and accept it? Then your question will show as "answered" in searches, which will make it more useful to any Seeker who comes along with the same problem? (Accepting your own answer is not only allowed it is encouraged.)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all very much for the help. I did save in windows and loaded into Unix. I checked my file, it has control M, carriage return, once I deleted \r, I was able to load successfully. Thank you all.